# How to resolve the class with properties?

Tags: c#, properties, autofac

I have the line of code like this:

```
var clientProfile = new ClientProfile { Id = user.Id, UserName = userDto.UserName };
```

I'm trying to resolve this class using Autofac. How can I make this simply?
Something like this:

```
var clientProfile = AutofacHostFactory
                    .Container
                    .ResolveWithProperty<ClientProfile>( 
                     Id = user.Id, UserName = userDto.UserName
                    );
```

Comment: Why do you want to resolve `ClientProfile` with Autofac? That class seems like a data object, not like a component (i.e. class with behavior).

Comment: Anyway I want to know how to initailize properties by Autofac..

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check out the documentation on [property and method injection](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html) as well as [how to pass parameters during resolve operations](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/parameters.html). Between the two of those with the included examples you should be on your way.